# How to remove thickbox background screen from asp.net page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tags, thickbox

I have a a href tag and a validate method in javascript

my aspx code is similar like this

```
<a onclick="validate();" href="PopUpPage.aspx?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=150&width=400"
      class="thickbox" id="AnchorImage" >
<img id="ColorImageButton" src="SiteImages.png" runat="server" />
</a>
```

When clicking on link I need to validate and remove thickbox

my javascript is similar like this

```
function validate() {

if (document.getElementById('<%=ColorImageButton.ClientID%>').src.indexOf('Red.png') >= 0) {
             document.getElementById('AnchorImage').removeAttribute('href');
             document.getElementById('AnchorImage').removeAttribute('class');
         }
 }
```

And I have two buttons to change image inside the anchor tag. based on Image set by using buttons i am removing the thickbox class. means if it is Green.png i need to show the popup window of thickbox.if Red.png I need to remove or disable thickbox or no action should not take place

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"  />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorImageButton.Src = "~/SiteImages/Red.png";
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorImageButton.Src = "~/SiteImages/Green.png";
}
```

validate is called when user click on the image inside the anchor tag, popup is not displaying if the condition satisfying. but still the black transparent screen of thickbox is appearing and user need to click on this. how i can solve this?

Comment: do you want to remove class="thickbox" in validate?

Comment: @ShoaibMuhammadKhan yes the same, I think that then only the background screen coming with thickbox will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the thickbox.js source code it doesn't give a way to cancel so try calling it manually.

e.g.
Remove the thickbox and href attributes from the anchor

```
<a onclick="validate(); return false;" href="#" id="AnchorImage">
    <img id="ColorImageButton" src="SiteImages.png" runat="server" />
</a>
```

In your validate function call tb_show to show the thickbox when necessary

```
function validate() {

    if (document.getElementById('<%=ColorImageButton.ClientID%>').src.indexOf('Red.png') >= 0) {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
       //tb_show(caption, url, imageGroup)
       tb_show(null, "PopUpPage.aspx?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=150&width=400", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. but the thickbox black background screen is still there.

Comment: I am new to jsfiddle.net. I am checking using that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the class="thickbox" change your java script like below

```
document.getElementById("AnchorImage").removeAttribute('class');
```

or else if you want to change the property the code below

eg: For textbox

```
document.getElementById("txt").removeAttribute("readonly",0);
```

(0,1) declares the property value as true or false.

Hope this helps you

Comment: by this code I can remove the thickbox attribute but the black background screen of thickbox is still there.

Comment: Will you post your code on jsfiddle? It will helpful to us to sove easily

Comment: I am new to jsfiddle.net. now I am checking using that.